# How many units are in the ring $(\Bbb Z/15\Bbb Z) \times (\Bbb Z/125\Bbb Z)$

Tags: ring-theory, finite-groups

How many units are in the ring $(\Bbb Z/15\Bbb Z) \times (\Bbb Z/125\Bbb Z)$

I am not sure how to count the units exactly because for smaller numbers I could make a multiplication chart and see which ones are equal to one. But $125$ is too large to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Hint:* If $A$ and $B$ are commutative rings with unity, then $(A \times B)^\times = A^\times \times B^\times$, where $R^\times$ is the group of units of the ring $R$.

Answer (score 0):

Consider Euler phi function and compute it at 125. So, $\phi(125) = 100$ is the number of units in $\frac{\mathbb{Z}}{125\mathbb{Z}}$ and similarly, $\phi(15) = 8$ is the number of units in $\frac{\mathbb{Z}}{15\mathbb{Z}}$. Now, use the counting techinque to compute the units is the product.

Comment: Can you specify the counting technique please? Thanks

Comment: Units in this ring would be of the form $(u_1, u_2)$ where $u_1$ is unit in the first ring and $u_2$ is the unit in second ring. For first, you have 8 choices and for the latter, you have 100 choices. So, how many choices are there for $(u_1, u_2)$?

Comment: Would there be 8? I am really confused

Comment: There would be 8×100= 800 units.